# Append() não funciona depois de remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu quero adicionar o botão converter e depois remover ele e adicionar o botão baixar no lugar, mas não está funcionando. Alguém sabe o porque. obs: Eu não quero usar hide.

```
 <button class="a">Add</button>
 <div class="input_fields_wrap"></div> 

 var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); 
 var x = 1;
 $('.a').click(function (){
 var t = x++;
 $(wrapper).append(

 '<div id="modal_line_arquivos">'+
 '<button class="converter">converter"'+(x)+
 '"</button>'+
 '</div>'
  );
  
  });

  $(".input_fields_wrap").on("click", ".converter", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent('div').find('button').remove();
  $(this).parent('div').append('<button class="converter">baixar</button>');
  });
```

Comment: Vc removeu o botão,  logo o segundo $(this) perde a referência. Só que vc tá fazendo o .html no elemento errado tb.

Comment: ok, @Sam. Fiz a correção mas o erro persiste. você poderia avaliar novamente?

Comment: Quando faz isso `$(this).parent('div').find('button').remove();` você está removendo o botão do documento implicando que o botão não mais possui ancestral e por consequência a próxima chamada `$(this).parent('div')` é nulo. Crie uma referência para o div como por exemplo  `let d = $(this).parent('div');` e passe a operar com `$(this).remove();  d.append('<button class="converter">baixar</button>');`.

Comment: Funcinou aqui, @Augusto. Muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score -3):

Crie uma variável para armazenar a referência que foi perdida após ser removida:

```js
var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); 
var x = 1;

$('.a').click(function () {
  var t = x++;
  
  $(wrapper).append(
    '<div id="modal_line_arquivos">' +
    '<button class="converter">converter"' + (x) + '"</button>'+'</div>'
  );
  
});

$(".input_fields_wrap").on("click", ".converter", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  let reference = $(this).parent('div');
  
  $(this).remove();
  reference.append('<button class="converter">baixar</button>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="a">Add</button>
<div class="input_fields_wrap"></div>
```